# Visualising each iteration of histogram plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I have a histogram plot of random number generation:

```
x=[0 1];
for iters = 1:10
particles=round(rand(100,1));
hist(particles,x)
```

Ideally I want to run this iteration many times and I want the histogram to reflect this; I want it to change with each run. However, it only shows the final run on the histogram. Using 'hold on' doesn't help, as this just plots all the histograms on top of each other.

I want it to be "animated", in the sense that I want each run to correspond to a different histogram and the plot to show this 'jumping' from histogram to histogram. So essentially I want to slow down the iteration process or something.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `pause(0.2),drawnow` after `hist(particles,x)`. Feel free to change `0.2` according to animation length you wish to see.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a loop and use pause, as an added bonus, you can even record an actual movie:

```
FIG = figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
vidObj = VideoWriter('file_name','MPEG-4');
vidObj.FrameRate = 20;
open(vidObj);

x=[0 1];
for iters = 1:10
    particles=round(rand(100,1));
    hist(particles,x)
    pause(timeGap)

    drawnow;
    F = im2frame(FIG);
    writeVideo(vidObj,F);    % Add frame to video
end

close(vidObj);
```